# What is app.lib and how do I import it into an Android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm an iOS developer trying to build an existing Android app on a Mac - yikes! I'm sure this is a simple question: I've got the project loaded in Eclipse, but it won't build due to the error:
"Missing required Java project: 'app.lib'"
Is this a standard Java library? Eclipse nicely displays a wizard to attempt to fix the problem by bringing up the Configure Build Path dialog - but where app.lib is listed as 'missing' -
Where do I get this library?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, app.lib is not a standard Java/Android library.

- Clean and rebuild your project
- Close it and reopen it

Try to remove it on your build path and see if you can build your project without it.